# How to show $(1-x)^2+(y+1)^2+(1-xy)^2\geq 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

> How to show $(1-x)^2+(y+1)^2+(1-xy)^2\geq 2$?

I want to show that $h(x,y)=(1-x)^2+(y+1)^2+(1-xy)^2$ has a global minimum in $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ where $h(1,0)=h(0,-1)=2$. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed we have $$h(x,y)-2=x^2 y^2 + x^2 - 2 x y - 2 x + y^2 + 2 y + 1=(y-x+1)^2+x^2y^2\geq0$$ See [this interesting script](http://www.princeton.edu/~aaa/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec15.pdf) for the theory behind decompositions like this.

Comment: Danke, das ist sehr gewitzt! :) Translation: Thank you, that's really slyish!

Comment: But is there an alternative? I feel like this wouldn't be the way to go in a test situation

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic In a test you can always look for all points such that $\nabla h(x,y)=0$ and check that $h$ is positive at these points. You will also need to study what happens as $|(x,y)|\to\infty$ but this is easy here because the fourth order term will dominate

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Please see here for the alternative method I described: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2058469/how-can-we-minimize-a-function-of-two-variables

Comment: Well, the second derivative test is enough to show a local maximum/minimum, not a global though

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Yes, but if a point is a global minimum then the gradient at that point will be $0$. So if you check all extremal points you only need to check what happens "at the boundary" i.e. what happens when $|(x,y)|\to\infty$, as said above